# How to properly abstract console.log color variables with messages

Tags: javascript, object, console, abstraction, console.log

I want to abstract my console.log() message into a variable. Here is the code:

I am utilizing console.log color messages.

```
console.log("%c Scenario 1.0:" + "%c [street number] + [direction] + [street name] + [suffix] + anything else", console.colors.bold.yellow, console.colors.white);
```

Which results in

Scenario 1.0: (in bold and yellow)

[street number] + [direction] + [street name] + [suffix] + anything else  (normal and white)

```
console.colors = {
    "gray": "color: #1B2B34;",
    "red": "color: #DB4C4C;",
    "orange": "color: #F99157;",
    "yellow": "color: #BADA55;",
    "green": "color: #99C794;",
    "teal": "color: #5FB3B3;",
    "blue": "color: #6699CC;",
    "purple": "color: #C594C5;",
    "black": "color: #000000;",
    "white": "color: #FFFFFF;",
    "brown": "color: #AB7967;",
}
console.colors.bold = {
    "gray": "font-weight: bold;" + console.colors.gray,
    "red": "font-weight: bold;" + console.colors.red,
    "orange": "font-weight: bold;" + console.colors.orange,
    "yellow": "font-weight: bold;" + console.colors.yellow,
    "green": "font-weight: bold;" + console.colors.green,
    "teal": "font-weight: bold;" + console.colors.teal,
    "blue": "font-weight: bold;" + console.colors.blue,
    "purple": "font-weight: bold;" + console.colors.purple,
    "black": "font-weight: bold;" + console.colors.black,
    "white": "font-weight: bold;" + console.colors.white,
    "brown": "font-weight: bold;" + console.colors.brown
}

  var caseConsoleLogColors = "console.colors.bold.yellow, console.colors.white";
    var scenario = {
        case1_0: "%c Scenario 1.0:" + "%c [street number] + [direction] + [street name] + [suffix] + anything else", caseConsoleLogColors,
        case1_1: "%c Scenario 1.1:" + "%c [street number] + [direction] + [street name]", caseConsoleLogColors,
        case2: "%c Scenario 2:" + "%c [street number] + [street name] + [suffix] - No cardinal direction, 3 items or more", caseConsoleLogColors,
        case3: "%c Scenario 3:" + "%c [street number] + [numeric street name]", caseConsoleLogColors,
        case4_0: "%c Scenario 4.0:" + "%c [street number] + [alphabet street name]", caseConsoleLogColors,
        case4_1: "%c Scenario 4.1 CONFLICT:" + "%c [street name] + [suffix]", caseConsoleLogColors,
        case5: "%c Scenario 5.0:" + "%c [direction] + [numeric street name]", caseConsoleLogColors,
        case6: "%c Scenario 6:" + "%c [direction] + [numeric street name] + [suffix] + anything else", caseConsoleLogColors
    }
 // works great
  console.log("%c Scenario 1.0:" + "%c [street number] + [direction] + [street name] + [suffix] + anything else", console.colors.bold.yellow, console.colors.white);

  // does not work
    console.log("%c Scenario 1.0:" + "%c [street number] + [direction] + [street name] + [suffix] + anything else", caseConsoleLogColors);

  // does not work
     console.log(scenario.case1);
```

This all works great. The problem is that I want to abstract the message and colors out of the console.log() and into a variable name, so I can just plop the variable inside, like this

```
console.log(scenario.case1_0)
```

But the console.log coloring and message breaks. It does not output a proper message nor color. How do I abstract this properly?

View JSbin with your browser console open:
https://jsbin.com/duxefogufo/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 2):

The colours being passed to the log need to be two separate arguments, not a single string.

```
var caseConsoleLogColors = "console.colors.bold.yellow, console.colors.white";
```

Should become:

```
var caseConsoleLogColors = [console.colors.bold.yellow, console.colors.white];
```

You then the combine the message and the colours into a single argument array as follows:

```
var message = ["%c Scenario 1.0:" + "%c [street number] + [direction] + [street name] + [suffix] + anything else"]  
var args = message.concat(caseConsoleLogColors);
```

Use the apply function to call console.log with the array of arguments:

```
console.log.apply(console, args);
```

It's important to specify the context as console, otherwise you'll get an error.

For the second example where you are taking strings from the scenario object, just use the scenario object to store the different messages but don't try and concatenate strings of message and colour at this point:

```
var scenario = {
    case1: "%c Scenario 1.0:" + "%c [street number] + [direction] + [street name] + [suffix] + anything else"
```

Then access the message from the scenario object, create an array for it and concat the colours array into it:

```
var message = [scenario.case1]
var args = message.concat(caseConsoleLogColors);
console.log.apply(console, args);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out and see how it goes and update soon.